# Get Alias of Sub Application from URL

Tags: c#, url

Is there any other way to get alias of sub application from url except simple parsing of string?

For example : `url = "http://localhost/subApp/index.aspx";`

I need this : `alias = "/subApp";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with the `Uri` class:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/subApp/index.aspx");
string alias = uri.Segments[1];
```

If there are more than one segments you could use this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/subApp/subApp2/index.aspx");

StringBuilder alias = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i < (uri.Segments.Count() -1); i++)
{
    alias.Append(uri.Segments[i]);
}
```

Comment: and in case if there will be more comlex variant of url : `http://localhost/subApp/subSubApp/index.aspx` ? How can i manage this?

Comment: @demo What is the excpected result in this example? Also subApp?

Comment: result : `/subApp/subSubApp`. Problem - i don't know how complex it can be.